I am Receiving an error as payload must be of type Object in nextjs using prisma
I am creating an signup route in next js where it taks an user email , password and username .

import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { sendVerificationEmail } from '@/helpers/sendVerificationEmail';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
       
        const  { username, email, password } = await request.json();
       

        if (!username || !email || !password) {
            console.log('Missing required fields:', { username, email, password });
            return new Response(
                JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Username, email, and password are required.',
                }),
                { status: 400 }
            );
        }

        const existingUserByUsername = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                AND: [{ username }, { isVerified: true }],
            },
        });

        if (existingUserByUsername) {
            console.log('Username already taken:', username);
            return new Response(
                JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Username is already taken.',
                }),
                { status: 400 }
            );
        }

  
        const existingUserByEmail = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { email },
        });

        const verifyCode = Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        if (existingUserByEmail) {
            if (existingUserByEmail.isVerified) {
                console.log('Email already verified:', email);
                return new Response(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'User already exists with this email.',
                    }),
                    { status: 400 }
                );
            }

            console.log('Updating unverified user:', email);
            const verifyCodeExpiry = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000);

            await prisma.user.update({
                where: { email },
                data: {
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    verifyCode,
                    verifyCodeExpiry,
                },
            });
        } else {
           
            console.log('Creating new user:', { username, email });
            const verifyCodeExpiry = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000);

            await prisma.user.create({
                data: {
                    username,
                    email,
                    password: hashedPassword,
                    verifyCode,
                    verifyCodeExpiry,
                    isVerified: false,
                    isAcceptingMessage: true,
                    messages: {
                        create: [],
                    },
                },
            });
        }

        const emailResponse = await sendVerificationEmail(email, username, verifyCode);
        console.log('Email response:', emailResponse);

        if (!emailResponse || !emailResponse.success) {
            console.log('Failed to send verification email:', emailResponse);
            return new Response(
                JSON.stringify({
                    success: false,
                    message: emailResponse?.message || 'Failed to send verification email.',
                }),
                { status: 500 }
            );
        }

        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify({
                success: true,
                message: 'User registered successfully. Please verify your email.',
            }),
            { status: 200 }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during registration:', error);

        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error registering user',
            }),
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}



I am using prisma as databse :
model Message{
    id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
    userId  Int 
    user User @relation(fields:[userId],references:[id])
    content String
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model User{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String @unique 
  email String @unique 
  password String 
  verifyCode String
  verifyCodeExpiry DateTime
  isVerified Boolean @default(false)
  isAcceptingMessage Boolean
  messages Message[]
}

As soon as user created an emailVerification email should go to user email .
I was receiving an error as :
 ⨯ TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null
    at AsyncLocalStorage.exit (node:async_hooks:358:14)
    at POST (./src/app/api/sign-up/route.ts:244:17)
 ⨯ TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null
    at frame (node_modules\next\src\server\patch-error-inspect.ts:89:42)
    at getSourcemappedFrameIfPossible (node_modules\next\src\server\patch-error-inspect.ts:179:32)
    at parseAndSourceMap (node_modules\next\src\server\patch-error-inspect.ts:234:23)
    at exit (node_modules\next\src\server\patch-error-inspect.ts:224:32)
    at apply (webpack://next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js:569:32)
    at apply (webpack://next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-server.node.development.js:593:32)
    at error (c:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\Mobile\bridge\src\app\api\sign-up\route.ts:256:16)
    at async AppRouteRouteModule.do (webpack://next/dist/src/server/route-modules/app-route/module.ts:529:14)
    at async AppRouteRouteModule.handle (webpack://next/dist/src/server/route-modules/app-route/module.ts:658:30)
    at async doRender (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:2504:29)
    at async responseGenerator (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3027:21)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3039:23)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3597:15)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:3659:23)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:1698:20)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\next-server.ts:1034:6)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\base-server.ts:1462:8)
    at async (node_modules\next\src\server\dev\next-dev-server.ts:514:13)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (node_modules\next\src\trace\trace.ts:143:13)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\dev\next-dev-server.ts:512:19)
    at async invokeRender (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:284:10)
    at async handleRequest (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:530:15)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\router-server.ts:576:6)
    at async Server.requestListener (node_modules\next\src\server\lib\start-server.ts:146:6)
  254 |         );
  255 |     } catch (error) {
> 256 |         console.error('Error during registration:', error);
      |                ^
  257 |
  258 |         return new Response(
  259 |             JSON.stringify({ {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
 POST /api/sign-up 500 in 3844ms

i have tried different payloads to test still it occur the problem .
I think it have some prisma database problem .

In my case, I forgot to add the database connection strings to the .env file
I hope it will help

I was also encountering a similar error with NextJs and Prisma. Turns out to be a bug with React19 and NextJs15. I got the solution from a reddit user. You need to add a specific line for this error to go away. Put your code in a try-catch block, and in the catch block, Do this:
For JavaScript -
catch(error){
    console.log("Error:", error.stack)  // Only console.log works here, anything else was throwing errors for me.
}

For TypeScript -
catch(error) {
    if (error instanceof Error){
        console.log("Error: ", error.stack)
    }
}

Lemme know if this works or not

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
